# issue with animation in swift playground

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, swift-playground

I'm totally new to animations with swift and I started this concept by using playground here's my code below I have no "idea" why it doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let liveViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let liveView = UIView(frame: liveViewFrame)
liveView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveView

let smallFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let square = UIView(frame: smallFrame)
square.backgroundColor = .purple
liveView.addSubview(square)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
    liveView.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Comment: its working fine on my end sir ...

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is working fine 
[image]